# How can I find out what action was taken as a result of a "helpful" flag?

Tags: support, flags

I flagged [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527939/how-to-find-the-number-of-numeric-starts-with-and-find-the-top-3-count-among-them) as "other" with a note that the user was repeatedly asking low-quality homework questions and then getting very cross when anyone suggested this looked like homework. My flag was marked as "helpful" but I can't tell what, if any, action was taken as a result. A lot of comments on the question (a back-and-forth between me and the asker) have been deleted, but that doesn't really address the underlying issue. Is there any way I can find out whether the user received a warning, say?

Answer (score 4):

Why would you want to know that?

You flagged it, the mods appreciated the flag and will act upon them. If the user is still stepping out of the line, flag again.

After your flag the business is between the mods and the user and doesn't involve you anymore (discussions between mods and users are mostly private, therefor there's also no need to tell you about them).

Comment: Fair point. I'm mostly just curious and I can see that it's not really any of my business! :-)